# Can we use a sql data field as column name instead?

Tags: mysql

First a query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='1'
```

Gives me a certain number of rows For example

```
id             |       context      |      cat     |    value
1                     Context 1            1           value 1
1                     Context 2            1           value 2
1                     Context 1            2           value 3
1                     Context 2            2           value 4
```

Now my problem instead of receiving the result in such way
I want it is this way instead

```
id      |   cat    |    Context 1     |  Context 2   
1            1           value 1          value 2       
1            2           value 3          value 4
```

Comment: What database server software do you use? Some have built in keywords that support this sort of thing (like SQL Server's `PIVOT`), whilst others would need you to do a `FULL JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  md.id, md.cat, m1.value AS context1, m2.value AS context2
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id, cat
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = 1
        ) md
LEFT JOIN
        mytable m1
ON      m1.id = 1
        AND m1.cat = md.cat
        AND m1.context = 'context 1'
LEFT JOIN
        mytable m2
ON      m2.id = 1
        AND m2.cat = md.cat
        AND m2.context = 'context 2'
```

Comment: Actually, I am not sure not there are only going to be two context only and I need distinct Cat not ID

Comment: @Starx: any query has a fixed number of fields in its output, defined by its structure. If you want variable columns, use dynamic `SQL`: use the `md` part as a template and append as many `LEFT JOIN` clauses as you need.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I have getting a error on this query. `Unknown column 'md.id' in 'field list'`

Comment: Oh... Distinct id, I tried with distinct cat.... Still, query works, but the values are missing... i get only `context 1` and `context 2` as value in both rows

Comment: @starx: sorry, fixed this too.

Comment: +1, Thank you for your help...I really learnt a lot from this example.  But in my case... there are going to variable column. :)

Answer (score 2):

*@updated - see comment # in code block 3 (MySQL) which was meant for debugging only from the console or HeidiSQL*

What you are looking for is called pivoting.
You have not stated what DBMS this is on, but for SQL Server, look in Books Online for the PIVOT operator - that could work if the categories are fixed.
If not, then you need dynamic sql, something like

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

-- generate the column names
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ',', '') + QuoteName(context)
from (select distinct context from mytable) T;

-- replace the column names into the generic PIVOT form
set @sql = REPLACE('
select id, cat, :columns:
from (select id, cat, context, value From mytable) p
pivot (max(value) for context in (:columns:)) pv',
':columns:', @sql)

-- execute for the results
exec (@sql)
```

Test data

```
create table mytable (id int, context varchar(10), cat int, value varchar(20))
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 1', 1 ,'value 1'
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 2', 1 ,'value 2'
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 1', 2 ,'value 3'
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 2', 2 ,'value 4'
```

The above is for SQL Server.  For **MySQL** use this instead, which follows the same technique.

```
SELECT @sql := NULL;
SELECT @sql := group_concat(
    'max(case when context=''',
    replace(context,'''',''''''),
    ''' then value end) `',
    replace(context,'`','``'),
    '`')
from (select distinct context from mytable) T;
SELECT @sql := concat(
    'select id, cat,',
    @sql,
    ' from mytable group by id, cat');
# SELECT @sql; # commented out, PHP sees this as the first result
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Based on your test data, plus two curlies (quote and backquote):

```
create table mytable (id int, context varchar(10), cat int, value varchar(20));
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 1', 1 ,'value 1';
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 2', 1 ,'value 2';
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 1', 2 ,'value 3';
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context 2', 2 ,'value 4';
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context''3', 1 ,'quote';
insert mytable select 1 ,'Context`4', 2 ,'backquote';
```

Comment: Your php application can execute a complex query (e.g. a stored procedure) on the database, just like it can execute the simple query in your question.

Comment: @Starx - MySQL solution added

Comment: @cyberwiki, I can see that your query is working perfectly... but I am not seeing the results table. I used phpmyadmin to test the code...

Comment: @Starx - I am confused. Are you saying that if/when you run the code verbatim (in a test db) it works perfectly? Maybe you translated that incorrectly in your code?

Comment: OH.. i am sorry for the confusion. I mean to say I am not receiving any result set to work with at PHP. but I can see the query is working with a `2 row(s) affected` message in phpmyadmin

Comment: @Starx - my mistake, I have updated to comment out the printing of the generated sql statement

Comment: I feel so dump... I get `bool(false)` as output.... Can you guide me..? I really appreciate your help so far

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.cat, t1.value as 'Context 1', t2.value as 'Context 2'
FROM mytable t1, mytable t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.cat = t2.cat and t1.context = 'Context 1' and t2.context = 'Context 2'
```

works if every ID/cat combination has both context 1 and context 2.